# Unable to find JerseyRxClient with RxJava working example

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2, jersey-client

I am trying to use rx jersey client and want to use rxjava Observables with it.
So I have tried a lot of use examples from the web and didn't found any complete working one. 
For example I have this simple code:

```
    Client cl = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    cl.register(RxObservableInvokerProvider.class);
    Invocation.Builder builder  = cl.target("fencyaddress.com").request();
    RxObservableInvoker inv = builder.rx(RxObservableInvoker.class);
```

And it fails with:

java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.rx(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljavax/ws/rs/client/RxInvoker;

Can one provide a good working example of jeseyrxclient with rxjavaObservables or rxjava2 flowables.

There was a bug like this but looks like it is still not solved and no notion of a workaround:
https://github.com/jersey/jersey/issues/3533

Comment: Can you show all your dependencies. Make sure you are using all the same versions for all your Jersey dependencies.

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.rx</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-rx-client-rxjava</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
        </dependency>

I also use dropwizard which in turn has a dependency from the jersey client.

rxjava is version 1.3.8
jersey-rx-client is version 2.25.1

Comment: Sorry for bad format of the comment, I just learn how to write hear)))

Comment: @Paul, It turns out this was a problem with versions. All the examples I saw in the net was using the 2.25 style but those classes are no more present in the 2.27.
Thanks for your answer.